# Plotting differential equation in sympy doesn't Work

Tags: python, plot, sympy

I've been studying programming to help physics course, so I tried to check some differential equations that I saw in my textbook by using Sympy. I success to make my code as a form of equation in LaTeX style, but It fails to plot the equation as a graph. How do I fix code to plot the equation?
(The equation presents Rabi Oscillation in a quasiclassical model)

I'm using jupyter notebook,

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp
import math
from sympy.plotting import plot
from sympy import I
from math import exp

sp.init_printing(use_latex=True)
```

```
t=sp.symbols('t')
a1=sp.symbols('a1',cls=sp.Function)
y1=(a1(t))
a2=sp.symbols('a2',cls=sp.Function)
y2=(a2(t))
h=sp.symbols('h')
V12,V21=sp.symbols('V12 V21')

d_eq1=sp.Eq(sp.diff(y1,t),(-I/(2*h))*V12*y2)
d_eq2=sp.Eq(sp.diff(y2,t),(-I/(2*h))*V21*y1)

sol=sp.dsolve([d_eq1,d_eq2],ics={a1(0):1,a2(0):0})
```

```
sol
```

> []: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHtx2.png

```
plot(sol[0],(t,0,100))
```

```
TypeError                                 Traceback 
(most recent call last)<ipython-input-17-9fa79dcd4775> in <module>----> 1 plot(sol[0],(t,0,100))

~\Anaconda3\envs\Qiskit\lib\site-packages\sympy\plotting\plot.py in plot(*args, **kwargs)
   1640     series = []
   1641     plot_expr = check_arguments(args, 1, 1)
-> 1642     series = [LineOver1DRangeSeries(*arg, **kwargs) for arg in plot_expr]
   1643 
   1644     plots = Plot(*series, **kwargs)
```

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: You may need to share `check_arguments`. It looks like that function returns `None` implicitly or explicitly

Comment: Your equation can't be plotted, as there are still 3 unknowns (`v12, v21, h`).   You'll need to provide values for them. Further, the solution seems to contain complex numbers, while `sp.plot` would plot reals.